# Homebrew installation problems (homebrew.devcmdrun)

Tags: git, macos, homebrew

I'm having problems using brew on mac osx sierra. Upon following the instructions and installing command line tools for mac my installation of brew never completes.

I'm using the following command:

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

Which gets me to:

```
==> This script will install:
/usr/local/bin/brew
/usr/local/share/doc/homebrew
/usr/local/share/man/man1/brew.1
/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_brew
/usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d/brew
/usr/local/Homebrew

Press RETURN to continue or any other key to abort
==> Downloading and installing Homebrew...
remote: Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
HEAD is now at 5b04152 Merge pull request #3133 from MikeMcQuaid/travis-umask
```

The thing freezes up at this point.
I've tried chowning local folder like some others suggested and there doesn't seem to be a problem with command line tools installation (as 'make' seems to be working). The problems seems lie on a command the installer is running which fails:

```
git config --file=/usr/local/Homebrew/.git/config --get homebrew.devcmdrun  <pid>
```

But i've been able to use git fine for other uses on this machine. Any ideas where I can go from here?

Answer (score 0):

This was resolved by upgrading the built in Apple GIT version with the official one from the website.